# OpenLayers Plugin and QGIS 2.4

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, qgis-plugins

I have installed QGIS 2.4 with the stand alone installer and the OSGeo4W too on three different computers. Two have Win7 64 and one vista 64. It seems that the OpenLayers plugin does not work any more. What I did was the following:

1) Open a GPX file with GPS tools

1.1) Once I converted the GPX to .shp and declare that I wanted the data in EPSG:4326

2) Tried to use OpenLayers plugin either with the GPX file or the .shp (in a new project)

This is what I get:

**Python Warning**

```
warning:C:/Users/Mapoteca/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_layer.py:146: DeprecationWarning: QgsMapCanvas.mapRenderer() is deprecated

if rendererContext.painter().device().logicalDpiX() != int(self.iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer().outputDpi()):

traceback:  File "C:/Users/Mapoteca/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_layer.py", line 109, in draw
self.render(rendererContext)
```

**Python Error (same message on another computer)**

```
An error has occurred while executing Python code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Mapo/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_layer.py",
line 109, in draw
self.render(rendererContext)
File "C:/Users/Mapo/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_layer.py", line 158, in render
for res in self.resolutions():
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`
```

Python version:
2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

QGIS version:
2.4.0-Chugiak Chugiak, 8fdd08a

Moreover I uninstalled the OpenLayers Plugin, since I wanted to reinstall it, but it is no longer on the list.

My question is if the plugin is not compatible with QGIS new version or this behaviour is just happening on my machines.

I have a 2.3 version and it shows the same symptoms.

Comment: I have the same errors and error messages too.  I've also just installed QGIS 2.4 running Windows 7.  Installed using the OSGeo4W (64 bit) installer.

Comment: Don't be in a hurry and wait: look at [QGIS user list: OpenLayers plugin QGIS 2.4](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/OpenLayers-plugin-QGIS-2-4-td5148663.html)

Comment: @gene: I think this should qualify as an answer.

Comment: I also think that gene´s comments qualify as an answer. Following the link it clarifies the issues.

Comment: Openlayers plugin has some problem in qgis 2.4 because of multithreading. https://twitter.com/PirminKalberer/status/482829223703621632

Comment: The update of the plugin was delayed. The issue should be fixed now.